# Use case of setValues raster

Tags: r, r-raster

I recently stumbled upon the `setValues()`form the `raster` package, but I am wondering what the use case of this function is. Is  there any advantage compared to normal subsetting and indexing:

```
r     <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)

#setValues Function
r     <- setValues(r, values=1, index=10)

#Normal indexing
r[10] <- 1
```

Both ways yield in the same result. However the documentation states that:

> While you can access the 'values' slot of the objects directly, you
>   would do that at your own peril because when setting values, multiple
>   slots need to be changed; which is what these functions do.

What does the author mean by peril here? And what slots remain unchanged, when I use normal subsetting and not the setValues function or is there any advantage in terms of perfomance?

Comment: When the author warns against directly modifying the 'values' slot, they're talking about not doing something like this: `r <- raster(matrix(1:9, nc=3)); r@data@values <- 100*(1:9)`. If you monkey around like that, directly modifying the low-level data structure, you're bypassing lots of nice stuff that's done for you without your being directly aware of it. Try (for instance) running `minValue(r)` before and after that direct assignment to the `values` data slot to see what I mean. And then do `getMethod("setValues", "RasterLayer")` for a more detailed look at what `setValues` does for you.

Comment: Careful also: the second and third line of code in your code block aren't actually doing the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic use-case for `setValues` is if want to assign a vector of cell values to a (perhaps empty) `RasterLayer`. E.g.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:100)
```

A more R-idiomatic variation is

```
values(r) <- 1:100
```

Indexing is typically used for a few cells

```
r[1:5] <- NA
```

But you can also use it to set values for all cells

```
r[] <- 1:100
```